# jQuery Mobile Long text listview with count indicator stays over long text

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a listview with the count indicator, and I would like that the long text would enshort before the count.

It works fine without the "ui-li-count" property, the text get "cut" correctly with the "..." at the end, but with the count, it gets not cutted before.

Page JQM 1.4.2:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="addresses" data-theme="b">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>izigo.mobile</h1></div>

        <div class="ui-content" role="main">
           <li><a href="" id="a1">Client name and very long description #1<span class="ui-li-count">3 km</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="" id="a2">Client name and very long description #2<span class="ui-li-count">3 km</span></a></li>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Any idea how to cut the text bedfore the count?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your code and tell us which version of jQM you are using.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have updated the question. Version is 1.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just increase the padding on the text container.  Try something like this:

```
.ui-listview >.ui-li-has-count>.ui-btn-icon-right {
    padding-right: 5.5em;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ewffr/)**

Comment: Great! But JQM was not supose to solve this by default?

Comment: i guess it makes an assumption about the width of the count bubble, it can't easily allow for every different situation. If your count bubble was 3 instead of 3 km, the default padding would work...

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help ;) Great job BTW with the JQM Blog ;)